# Record voice until user stops speaking?

Tags: c#, audio, speech-recognition, windows-phone

I am trying to make a command-based service for Windows Phone. I do not wish to use the inbuilt speech functionality in Windows Phone 8 for this, since it needs to be Windows Phone 7 compatible as well. Furthermore, I do not want to use any external libraries as for now.

I would like to be able to record the user's voice until he stops speaking. But how can I detect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no easy or built-in ways in WP7, so you will have to develop your own voice recognition system, which I don't suggest to anyone. You should probably limit the voice functionality to WP8, or you'll find yourself reinventing the wheel for a dying version of Windows Phone with no future.